# Как добавить в статичный html-сайт функцию блога?

Tags: html, static

Здравствуйте. Хотел спросить. Есть сайт фотографа на HTML. Есть ли возможность добавить функцию блога, и если да, как это реализовать?

Comment: Только сажать на движок. Можно блог вынести в поддиректорию сайта, а сайт оставить статикой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

либо сделать сайт не статичным, либо -

- ведите блог на популярной платформе соцсети (фб/вк/жж/medium), а на сайт добавьте виджет от нее